# Discord bot consistently taking long time to send messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a very simple discord bot running in python 3.6.9.

Any time I call either of the 2 commands (ping or whenmonster), the first call takes upwards of 30 seconds to respond to discord with its message. On subsequent calls, it takes considerably less time, less than a second.

If I wait 30 seconds without calling any commands, the bot is once again slow, even after previously responding just fine.

- Nothing shows in the log, no sort of gateway reset, no errors
  handled.
- I kicked the bot out of the server and re-invited, and the behavior
  persists.
- I don't think I'm accidentally spamming the server, so the bot
  shouldn't be hitting the built-in discord timeout.
- We have other bots in the server that don't exhibit this behavior.
- When I run the ping command, latency always comes back to just 0.1
  seconds.
- I tried just printing the websocket object to see if the bot was making a new one, seems to always be the same one

Is this a discord API thing? I just don't get what's going on to cause this. I'm literally crying thinking about all the funny things my friends are missing out on not using my bot. I just want them to know whenever they want, without delay, how many days there are until Godzilla just whoops King King back to monke island. Preciate any help!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

token = my_token


class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in!')
        print('Username: {0.name}\nID: {0.id}'.format(self.user))


bot = MyBot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong! {}'.format(round(bot.latency, 1)))

@bot.command()
async def whenmonster(ctx):
    monster_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 31)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = monster_time - now
    days = delta.days
    seconds = delta.seconds % 60
    minutes = (delta.seconds // 60) % 60
    hours = (delta.seconds //3600)
    msg = 'Time remaining until Kong gets his ass whooped: {} days, {} hours, {} minutes, {} seconds'.\
          format(days, hours, minutes, seconds)
    await ctx.send(msg)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Have you tried to form your time converter into a function and reduce the code blocks in the command itself?

Comment: Ah, I have not, but I don't think that would matter in this case. I can call whenmonster, itll be slow the first time, then call it again right after it replies in chat, and it'll respond immediately.

Comment: I took your piece of code and ran the situations that you described, and it runs perfectly fine to me. The only thing I change was
`monster_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 31)`
`now = datetime.datetime.now()`
to
`monster_time = datetime(2021, 3, 31)`
`now = datetime.now()`
which I don't think it makes any difference. So I don't think your issue has to do with the code itself.

Comment: Do you host it local? Is enough space available? For me everything worked fine/fast.

Comment: I host on a lil NUC running Ubuntu 18.04 w/ 8 GB of ram and 256 GB of storage on an SSD (with plenty of empty space). I live in CA whereas my friend lives in IL (although I don't know where the discord server is actually hosted). But like I said, ping is pretty low and once I run a command once, it's snappy for a bit.

Comment: Could be a server issue then. Have you tried requesting the ping with `.format(round(bot.latency * 1000)*?` Your code gives out `0.1` which is not really a ping

Comment: Have you tried the same source code on a different computer / network ? It could be that your router is slowing down those packet specifically as I don't see anything wrong with the code at first glance. 

Also, have you tried running it via a different way (in an IDE if you run it via terminal or vice-versa) ?

Comment: Alright, I whipped up a venv on my Windows 10 desktop and it works just fine. I don't know what the issue could be. Either it's the fact that it's Windows vs Linux or it's network differences between the two computers. I haven't done anything network-wise besides forward a few ports for servers I run on the NUC.

Comment: All I can suggest is to either make the code more efficient or that your pc performance may not be good enough :/ this could be because; you are running other applications at the same or that your pc just isnt good :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the DNS settings on my router were the default ISP, switching to google for primary and backup made the resolution much snappier.